# DRY paramiko_expect interactions

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm using `paramiko` and `paramiko_expect` to interact with a remote machine over SSH.

```
import paramiko
from paramiko_expect import SSHClientInteraction

user1 = 'admin'
pass1 = 'admin'

user_prompt = '.*\$ '   

# SSH to host1
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='host1', username=user1, password=pass1)

# Interact with SSH client
with SSHClientInteraction(ssh_client, display=True) as interact:
    interact.send('rm -f somefile')
    interact.expect(user_prompt)
    interact.send('mv file1 file2')
    interact.expect(user_prompt)

ssh_client.close()
```

Is there a way to wrap/decorate or otherwise remove some of the duplicate statements? Instead of:

```
interact.send('rm -f somefile')
interact.expect(user_prompt)
```

Do something like:

```
send_and_expect('rm -f somefile', user_prompt)
```

I don't really know how to get started. How do I "share" the context with a function outside of the context manager. The only rough idea I could come up with was something like but haven't tried it yet:

```
def send_and_expect(interact_ctx, cmd, prompt):
    interact_ctx.send(cmd)
    interact_ctx.expect(prompt)
```

Comment: The "context" is just an object.  You can pass it to other functions as you like.  This is done all the time with file handles.  e.g. `with file(foo) as f: do_something(f)`.  You can pass `interact` to  `send_and_expect()` without any trouble.  The only thing that's generally a no-no is passing the handle to something that stores it somewhere or otherwise keeps a reference to it.  That's usually asking for trouble.

Comment: @jq170727, thanks. I was overthinking it. I made a separate function to handle the sending of the command and expecting the prompt.